# Kill slow command after some time and return value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I've got a piped TASKLIST | FINDSTR command, which can take long time to finish. I don't want to wait too long for it, so I want to stop searching with FINDSTR and just get ERRORLEVEL 1 value, after for example 5s.

This script got to look if the specific EXE is running, and if it's not - open it.

```
@echo off
:B
set Poro=CapsuleFarmerEvolved.exe
TASKLIST /fi "imagename eq %Poro%" 2>nul | FINDSTR /i %Poro%
if ERRORLEVEL 0 (GOTO :B) else (start "" CapsuleFarmerEvolved.exe)
GOTO :B
```

I've tried adding timeout before the TASKLIST, but since it's piped, it doesn't work.
I was wondering maybe about creating a different .bat with this exact command and somehow kill the whole process, then return the value to the main script.
That is my first take to create a script, so please forgive me lack of basic knowlege, but I'd tried my best before posting this

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding. Never have I known tasklist to take any longer than a fraction of a second to list a specific image name. If listing all processes, it may take a little longer, but never five seconds, and certainly not more. IMO there is something you're not telling us.

Comment: @Compo the thing is, that when the EXE is closed, it searches for it infintely, but it exists nowhere. That's why I would like to terminate it after x time

Comment: Tasklist does not search, it lists all running processes. If your process is not running, tasklist will almost immediately know.

Comment: @Compo alright, so I've made a mistake with explaining this. The problem is with the findstr command taking too long, to find a process (because it doesn't exist), so that's what I would like to terminate.

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` is always TRUE. `if errorlevel n` means "if errorlevel is `n` **OR GREATER THAN `n`**" You need `if not errorlevel 1 goto B` then `start` on the next line to avoid the parentheses

Comment: No, `findstr`, reads only the immediate result, it searches only in that output. Also, there's no need to use findstr, if you're just using the same imagename, as the search pattern, just use find for that. If you want to use findstr, be aware that `.` is a special wildcard metacharacter.

Comment: Please add the resulting code where you added the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, however this is still a ridiculous idea, i.e. using a never-ending script to monitor, and restart an application, when it is no longer running.

```bash
@Echo Off
Set "Poro=CapsuleFarmerEvolved.exe"

:Loop
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "Status Eq Running" /Fi "ImageName Eq %Poro%" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%Poro%" 1>NUL || Start "" "P:\athTo\%Poro%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL
GoTo Loop
```

Comment: Thank you for this code and tips. I understand, that this may sound like a stupid way of dealing with a problem, but the app tends to shutdown itself sometimes.